# License key generator using C#

Tags: c#-3.0

In this line there is a some mistake want to know the correct line:

```
int value = km.LoadSuretyFile(string.Format(@"{0}key.lic", Application.StartupPath), ref lic);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We'd like to help you, but your question doesn't contain much information. Could you please Edit your question and provide more details such as what you are trying to do, what error message you are receiving and what you expecting it to do? That way, you'll be more likely to receive a useful Answer. Thank you.

Comment: i followed through you tube license key generator using c# in that about part is not displaying

Comment: that about is a session in that it is not displaying only product Id is displaying remaining things is not displaying

Comment: followed https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ctP910qdHhA

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ufnd2op8dpI followed this links in you tube

Answer (score 0):

A minor mistake while coding

"int value = km.LoadSuretyFile(string.Format(@"{0}\key.lic", Application.StartupPath), ref lic);"